# Using --check on a md5sum command generated checksum file is failing

Tags: powershell, cygwin, md5sum

I'm encountering an error when I try and run `md5sum -c` on a checksum file I generated. I should mention that I'm running this from PowerShell (as a script will be running this eventually) and this is the cygwin version of `md5sum`.

I have a test file, `jira_defect.txt` and I've created a checksum like this:

```
md5sum jira_defect.txt > result.md5
```

This gives a file with the following:

```
7d559b59459052f274e290b5e01a5485 *jira_defect.txt
```

But when I run

```
md5sum -c result.md5
```

I get the infamous error message

> result.md5: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found

I've tried this again with the `-t` option, which removes the asterisk, but this hasn't made a difference.

Comment: Do line endings on the `result.md5` file make any difference?

Comment: It looks like they have different line endings, yes. That must me it. The PowerShell md5 file is UCS-2 / Win and the Command Prompt file is 1252 / Unix, at least according to WinMerge.

Comment: If you make this into an answer, I'll mark as answered.

Comment: Encoding is certainly another possibility. I wasn't talking about that but it would certainly be a problem if powershell wrote a UTF-16 file and md5sum wasn't expecting that. Figure out a solution (save to variable and use set-contents or similar perhaps?) and write it all up as an answer yourself. I don't have the context to come up with a full solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the redirection operator to write the checksums to an output file causes the file to be created with the default encoding (Unicode). `md5sum` expects an ASCII file. Use `Set-Content` (or `Out-File`) to save the file with ASCII encoding:

```
md5sum jira_defect.txt | Set-Content result.md5 -Encoding ASCII
```

You can also work with Unicode files if you pipe their content into `md5sum`:

```
Get-Content result.md5 | md5sum -c
```

Demonstration:

```
PS C:\> md5sum .\test.ps1 > result.md5
PS C:\> md5sum -c .\result.md5
C:\md5sum.exe: .\result.md5: no properly formatted MD5 checksum lines found
PS C:\> Get-Content .\result.md5 | md5sum -c
.\test.ps1: OK
PS C:\> md5sum .\test.ps1 | Set-Content result.md5 -Encoding ASCII
PS C:\> md5sum -c .\result.md5
.\test.ps1: OK
```